# 46- and 64-bit integers

Tags: computer-science, binary, computational-mathematics, floating-point

> Some Cray supercomputers used to support 46-bit and 64-bit integer
>   data types. What are the maximum and minimum values that we could
>   express in a 46-bit integer? in a 64-bit integer?

Is my thinking correct that the ranges would be $\pm 2^{46}$ and $\pm 2^{64}$, correspondingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost.

With $n$ bits, we can represent $2^n$ distinct values. For *unsigned* integer types, we can thus cover the range from $0$ to $2^n-1$. And with *signed* integer types (two's complement with symmetric range), we can cover $-2^{n-1}$ to $2^{n-1}-1$.